# Android landscape orientation. Emulator doesn't respond

Tags: android, emulation

[screenshot http://sdl1.4pda.ru/1862622/image/jpeg/portrait.JPG?00169e49ceae42635003442300000000de9e7e77de71680003e699507907d6e9](http://sdl1.4pda.ru/1862622/image/jpeg/portrait.JPG?00169e49ceae42635003442300000000de9e7e77de71680003e699507907d6e9)
[screenshot http://sdl4.4pda.ru/1862623/image/jpeg/Landscape_mode.JPG?00169e49ceae42635003442e00000000e2f203d397cc0154fd07c1a111773c1a](http://sdl4.4pda.ru/1862623/image/jpeg/Landscape_mode.JPG?00169e49ceae42635003442e00000000e2f203d397cc0154fd07c1a111773c1a)

---

Good day! 
I've faced with a problem - Android emulator doesn't respond on orientation change!
Version 2.3.3.
You can see home screen on the picture. In my app I have 2 folder - layout, layout-land - and I expect Android to do turn for me (setContentView(R.layout.main) should chose right layout), as it was said in the book. Both files have name main.xml

Comment: The 'home screen' doesn't change orientation. If you created the AVD in portrait orientation then it will stay like that even if you change orientation in the emulator. The layout files only apply to your app when it's running and the screenshot doesn't show any running apps.

Comment: I've changed them. Thanks I didn't know about it

Comment: check to see in your manifest there is not a line android:configchang="  " if yes than remove and deploy your project again & and if still not work than try to deploy project in Android Device Rather Than Emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes some times this is the problem with **Android emulator 2.3.3**

To again get portrait mode click on the home and click you app icon again.

This is the only problem in emulator and coming to mobile it wont happen like this

Comment: Thanks, i'll try to launch it on Android 2.2